# How to work with img src in JavaScript in Laravel Vite

Tags: javascript, laravel, vite, laravel-vite

I don't understand this Vite documentation. My images should be in the resources folder, but the JS code still executes in the public folder. If css reads images without any problems ( background: url(../img/1.png), then JS will not do that. It wants to see that image in the public folder. And even if I write the full path to the image on the example of.

```
$("<img />", {
   src: '../../../../img/interface/dexPodium.png',
}).appendTo(this);
```

I still won't see it unless I do it like this.

`const imgUrl = new URL('../../../../../img/interface/dexPodium.png', import.meta.url);`

But, after the build, the images will be available in the public folder, so why should I write if it will be like

`const imgUrl = new URL('./img/interface/dexPodium.png', import.meta.url);`.

What am I doing wrong, and what is the correct way to specify paths to images in my JS? All the answers I found are Vue-related.

Answer (score 0):

You can import images directly in your JavaScript code in Vite, and Vite will handle the path resolution for you. This works in both development and production builds.

```js
import imgUrl from '../../../../img/interface/dexPodium.png';

$("<img />", {
   src: imgUrl,
}).appendTo(this);
```

In this code, `import imgUrl from '../../../../img/interface/dexPodium.png';` imports the image file and assigns its resolved URL to the `imgUrl` variable. You can then use this variable as your image's `src` attribute.

This way, you don't need to worry about the exact path of the image file in the public folder. Vite will automatically handle the path resolution for you.